# How to generate firebase incremental counter with push

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

hiii... any advice how to make increment counter in firebase 
im already using this code

```
firebase.database().ref(‘myData/' ).once('value', function(qTotal) {
    total = qTotal.numChildren() + 1;
    console.log(" counter" + total);
    var queId = firebase.database().ref(‘myData/').push({
      counter : total,
      dateCreated: Date()
    }).key;
}
```

but sometime numChildren()  generate same counter when data insert very fast..

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this in the simplest way possible, you can use a transaction:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref(‘myData/' );
ref.transaction(function(qTotal) {
    var current = qTotal ? qTotal.numChildren() : 0;
    var total = current + 1;
    var queId = ref.push().key;
    qtotal[queId] = {
      counter : total,
      dateCreated: Date()
    };
    return qTotal;
}
```

But increasing a counter across many concurrent users is going to lead to scalability problems. Each user will have to download the total data in order to add an item to it.

To learn more about this and how Firebase recommends you model such lists, read this blog post: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: thanks... then how the good way to give each user unique incremental number ( for their reference ).......

Comment: and also to process it  FIFO way

Comment: You're already calling `push()`, which generates a unique ID for you.

Comment: sorry i mean ... meaningfull number for human [1,2,3....] ( user have idea when their task will process) push generate long string

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'numChildren' of null
    at Object.update (controlers.js:2019)

Comment: Yeah, the should be prepared to get a `null` value. Even when you *know* that there is a value, the transaction handler will often be invoked with a `null` value initially.

Comment: thanks frank node created but still fail to update TypeError: Cannot set property '-KUV4I-iCuc-J2TlFTWt' of null
    at Object.update (controlers.js:2208)
    at di (firebase.js:461)

Comment: then how to prepared null value for updating  process ?